Filtering intersections to exclude artificial boundaries in Shapely
I'm working on a project where I need to find intersections between contours using the Shapely library. However, I'm running into an issue where some of the intersection points are incorrectly identified on the artificial boundaries (the closing paths of the contours) rather than within the actual curves.
How can I implement a stricter filtering condition to ensure that intersections are only considered valid if they occur within the actual curves and not on these artificial boundaries?
I've tried using is_simple and is_valid properties to filter out invalid geometries, but I'm still getting some intersections on these unwanted paths.
def find_intersections(lines1, lines2, lines3):
intersections = []
for line1 in lines1:
    for line2 in lines2:
        # Find the intersection between lines1 and lines2
        intersection12 = line1.intersection(line2)
        
        if not intersection12.is_empty:
            for line3 in lines3:
                # Find the intersection between the result and lines3
                intersection123 = intersection12.intersection(line3)
                
                if not intersection123.is_empty:
                    # Check if the intersection is a simple and valid geometry
                    if isinstance(intersection123, (Point, LineString)):
                        if intersection123.is_simple and intersection123.is_valid:
                            intersections.append(intersection123)
                    else:
                        for geom in intersection123.geoms:
                            if geom.is_simple and geom.is_valid:
                                intersections.append(geom)

return intersections

Here is the figure illustrating the issue:

We have three intersections, but only one is valid, corresponding to the intersection of the three colored curves. The other two intersections, located in the upper left, are incorrect and represent the meeting of the dashed lines.

Why wouldn't you get intersection points at locations ~ -150,150, 150,150, 150,-150 & 50,-200? Are trying to identify locations where all 3 lines intersect at the same location, rather than any intersection point?

I think you will have to share your data somehow. I've created a geopackage table with three lines in it, looking like yours, and intersect them using geopandas. I dont get intersections at the left side: https://imgur.com/yRBrsdk.png

Try using this method of intersecting the geometries: intersections = reduce(lambda line1, line2: line1.intersection(line2), [line1, line2, line3]), see reduce
